# Asset Pipeline: Trouble on deploying my Rails 3.1 application with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and Capistrano. I have a problem on make the application to work in production mode (the remote machine is running Ubuntu 10.4 - my local machine is a MacOS running Snow Leopard 10.6.7).

When I deploy with Capistrano I get this error:

```
uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
```

When I try to access a web page I get this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled)
```

**What I should to do in order to make the application to work in production mode on the remote machine?**

---

In my `Capfile` file I have:

```
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
load 'deploy/assets'
```

In my `Gemfile` file I have:

```
group :production do
  gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer'
end
```

If I comment the `load 'deploy/assets'` I do not get anymore the `uninitialized constant Rake::DSL` but I get still the `ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled)` error.

Comment: Do you precompile assets on production?

Comment: @Mike Bevz - Do you mean if I run the `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` command? If you mean that, I run that command in the remote server console\terminal but I get: `rake aborted!
system/logo.png isn't precompiled
  (in /<my_application_path>/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)`

Comment: yes, I meant assets:precompile. What does cap deploy:check say?

Comment: @user12882 Can you show `production.rb` file?

Comment: Are you referencing the image in your css file via `image_path('system/logo.png')`? The sass pipeline has some helper functions for this. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

```
"
If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript 
files to include, you can add them to the precompile array:

config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']
"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `config.assets.compile = true` in production.rb. 
Hope that helps.

Comment: I tryed that and it doesn't work. I get a `ActionView::Template::Error (<my_css_file> isn't precompiled)`.

Comment: You shouldn't be live compiling assets on in production. Set assets.compile = false and make sure your cap deploy script precompiles before the symlink process.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create new Rails 3.1 project with scaffolding and deploy it. If everything will be ok, compare configs and other files with your real project.