# Cannot precompile all css in rails application though rake assets:precompile

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails application and try to deploy it to my local apache server now right.

I tried to precompile the css,javascript file though the command `rake assets:precompile` and no errors came out.

However, I cannot not access the website though localhost properly and I checked the log file of production.

Error :

> ActionView::Template::Error (scaffolds.css isn't precompiled):
>       3: 
>       4:   Pragprog Books Online Store
>       5: 
>       6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "scaffolds" %>
>       7:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "depot", :media => "all" %> -->
>       8:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "pagination" %>
>       9:    app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in
>   `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1763484413904368549_70243433398420'

It seems that the scaffolds.css cannot be precompiled with the command.

I have changed the config to `config.assets.compile = true` and my website works. :)
But I want to know why the command cannot precompile that css.

Comment: Rails does not try to precompile scaffold.css because you didn't tell him to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510920/asset-pipeline-trouble-on-deploying-my-rails-3-1-application-with-capistrano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out these lines in your production.rb (or whatever environment you are using), which are probably still commented out:

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
# config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

Simply use this option to specify additional assets to precompile, for example:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.scss *.coffee *.css )
```

Comment: But which approach is better?

Comment: In production, it's better to precompile your assets since that way they can be served as static assets by the web server (as opposed to the app server). This speeds up things considerably. If you use `config.assets.compile = true`, the assets are compiled (or in the case of CSS, served) on the fly by the app server, which is slower.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiousity did you add it to your application.css manifest file?